# Find a subset of numbers that equals to the target weighted average and target sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

There is a SQL server table containing 1 million of rows. A sample data is shown below.
Percentage column is computed as = ((Y/X)* 100)

```
+----+--------+-------------+-----+-----+-------------+
| ID | Amount | Percentage  |  X  |  Y  |      Z      |
+----+--------+-------------+-----+-----+-------------+
|  1 |     10 | 9.5         | 100 | 9.5 | 95          |
|  2 |     20 | 9.5         | 100 | 9.5 | 190         |
|  3 |     40 | 5           | 100 | 5   | 200         |
|  4 |     50 | 5.555555556 |  90 | 5   | 277.7777778 |
|  5 |     70 | 8.571428571 |  70 | 6   | 600         |
|  6 |    100 | 9.230769231 |  65 | 6   | 923.0769231 |
|  7 |    120 | 7.058823529 |  85 | 6   | 847.0588235 |
|  8 |     60 | 10.52631579 |  95 | 10  | 631.5789474 |
|  9 |     80 | 10          | 100 | 10  | 800         |
| 10 |     95 | 10          | 100 | 10  | 950         |
+----+--------+-------------+-----+-----+-------------+
```

Now I need to find the rows such that their amount value add up to a given Amount and weighted average matches to the given Percentage.
For example, if the target Amount =365 and target Percentage=9.84, then from the given dataset, we can say that rows with ID=1,2,6,8,9,10 form the subset which will match the given targets.

```
Amount = 10+20+100+60+80+95
       = 365 
Percentage = Sum of (product of Amount and Percentage)/Sum of (Amount)
(I am using Z column to store the products of Amount and Percentage to make the calculations easier)
       = ((10*9.5)+(20*9.5)+(100*9.23077)+(60*10.5264)+(80*10)+(95*10))/     (10+20+100+60+80+95)
       = 9.834673618
```

So the rows 1,2,6,8,9,10 matches the given target sum and target weighted average.

Proposed algorithm should work on the 1 million rows and main objective is to achieve the match on the weighted average (Percentage) with Amount as much close as possible to the target Amount.

I found few questions on the stackoverflow which are related to match the target sum. But my problem is to match two target attributes Sum and weighted average.

Which algorithm can be used to achieve this?

Comment: This seems difficult. Basically you are asking for a bi-criteria approximation algorithm. I would guess that no such algorithm exists unless some sensible restrictions are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Since the target "Percentage" is only approximate (therefore not an actual constraint), let's try removing it and find a solution for `Amount`. This can only make the problem easier.

What's left is the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete. There are simple exponential-time solutions, and sneaky pseudo-polynomial-time solutions, but I don't think any of them will be practical for a table with 10<sup>6</sup> rows.

If this is an academic exercise, I suggest you write up the cleverest pseudo-polynomial-time solution you can come up with. If it's a task in the real world, I suggest you go back to the person who gave it to you, explain that an exact solution is impractical, and negotiate for an approximate solution.

Comment: I agree with Beta. Maybe it is worth looking at this resource explaining the concept: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem

Comment: This is a real world task. My main focus is to achieve the match on the weighted average value instead on the sum. On the sum value approximation is allowed but not on the weighted average. Is this is possible to achieve in the SQL? or dynamic language?

Comment: @Vin: That's the exact opposite of the example you gave, but yes, you can ignore the sum and look for the best match to the weighted average (or a perfect match, depending on what you mean by "approximation is not allowed"). That's a variant of the Subset Sum problem, and I don't see a faster way to solve it. The choice of language doesn't matter.